# Label tubing for particular uses?

Tags: tubing

I recently had to repurpose the tube I normally use to run off wort from my kettle into the fermentor as a blowoff tube instead.  I'm planning on getting a new tube to use for running off the wort in the future, because it doesn't seem like a good idea to run chilled wort through even a thoroughly cleaned blowoff tube.

How can I label these tubes of similar diameter and length so I can keep using them for the same purpose from batch to batch?  Solutions that will survive sanitizing and cleaning are strongly preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You could use electrical tape, it comes in different colors and it would resist washing.  The color would be your code to designate its purpose and length.

I have no other ideas for now, anyone else?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend even high quality electrical tape. The adhesive is very goey and messy over time. Which is great for maintaining noncunductive seals but not for labels. I would use wide platic bag ties attached losely they are washable and a perm marker works well on them.

Comment: @Evil Zymurgist, good idea, some sort of zip tie would work and they come in different colors as well.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, get silicone tube that you can boil, and standardize all your fittings to that tube. I use the same two pieces of tube for wort recirculation, chilled wort drain and blow-off; no cross-infection even with Brett/Lacto so far.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use different lengths? Shorter (or slightly shorter) tube for blow off or run off as required?